# App SDK migration from 27.0.2 to 27.1.0 failed (crash)

Tags: android

I've just upgraded my Gradle this morning with the new SDK:

```
    // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'
```

Unfortunately now there is a crash during my first Activity starts. This Activity has not layout. It worked perfectly before this SDK upgrade...

```
  03-06 10:20:33.117 18722-18722/com.xxx.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.azeoo.dev, PID: 18722
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.dev/com.xxx.ui.intro.WelcomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class LinearLayout
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class LinearLayout
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class LinearLayout
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:202)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1006)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:1776)
          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2613)
          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2686)
          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2049)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:175)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:145)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
          at com.xxx.ui.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:759)
          at com.xxx.ui.intro.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:45)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Thank you very much guys for your support!

Comment: change your `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` to `buildToolsVersion "27.1.0"`

Comment: share your xml file of WelcomeActivity class

Comment: @SantanuSur it doesn't exist! https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Comment: @AbhinavGupta : I have no XML layout. This Activity works withoutUI.

Comment: then share this `WelcomeAcivity` class

Comment: then try removing the `buildToolsVersion`

Comment: @SantanuSur why remove the buildToolsVersion?

Comment: you are using android studio 3.0.1 ? ryt ? go to the *setting -> sdk -> sdk tools* you can see  **Android SDK Build-Tools installed** build tools version is not required.. !! so try removing it.. !!

Comment: @SantanuSur : perfect that was the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: @apmartin1991 i faced the same problem earlier so i recommended.., it was a valid recommendation !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your

`buildToolsVersion` from your **app-level gradle file** in case you want to upgrade to `27.1.0`. So if you put 
`buildToolsVersion 27.0.2`

or `buildToolsVersion 27.0.3`

there might be a **conflict** cause `buildToolsVersion 27.1.0` **is not released yet.**

> So, removing the `buildToolsVersion x.x.x` might do the trick !!

**Edit 1**

Even though removing buildToolsVersion might work, i would recommend to stick to `27.0.2` because `27.1.0` is causing some **undesired crashes** and has a few `bugs`.
One of which is :-

[java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView$InnerLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174102/java-lang-classcastexception-android-support-v7-widget-activitychooserviewinne)

Even google has announced it ( in GOOGLE ISSUE  TRACKER ). So , guys better stick to `27.0.2` untill the *fixed and stable version is released.*