# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView$InnerLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat

Tags: android, classcastexception, android-constraintlayout

Switching from LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout throwing this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ActivityChooserView$InnerLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
```

The error occurs when i try to inflate the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in my fragment.

My menu which I inflate :-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">   
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        />
</menu>
```

My `onCreateOptionsMenu(..)`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {     
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.customerdetail, menu);      
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) 
    MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);         
 // If i comment out this whole part everything is fine !!
 }
```

**Edit** :- ScreenShot of the log:-

[image]

**Update** :- Adding the `app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"` item causes the error.

As suggested by ShaneCoder dropping down to `27.0.2` / changing to `LinearLayout` removes the error but i want to know

> Why is `27.1.0` is throwing such error at runtime while inflating Class,`android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` ? (is it a bug in `27.1.0` )

Comment: check if you are using  linear layout somewhere in the activity

Comment: even that was my first reaction.. i removed all possible `linear Layouts` even in the fragments..!! @Redman

Comment: Somewhere in your Java code you are Cast Linear Layout with LinearLayoutCompat

Comment: Nope i havent, i checked all of those before posting the question !! @Akash

Comment: Please post full stacktrace, not only the error

Comment: Also, why do you have a constraint layout immediately inside another?

Comment: adding the full stacktrace says `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 31914.` @cricket_007 and i wrapped another constraint layout in because i could not give `paddingbottom` to the immediate child of the `ScrollView`

Comment: Okay, then add the exception message plus at least 4 lines that say "Caused by", and everything between

Comment: the edited part is all i get in the logcat !!  no such crash exception "caused by" exception(`except the classCastException`)...i searched but found none with this error !! @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 added the screenshot of the logcat !!

Comment: Are you sure the constraint layout is the issue? Are you sure this exception is related to your application? Can you make a [mcve], please?

Comment: okay sure ,i will check it out ..by making a short demo !!

Comment: `at ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionMenu`... Unless you're loading this layout into a Toolbar or a Share action, I don't think the ConstraintLayout is there problem.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks !! i reached to a conclusion now and i reduced the question to as **minimal** as possible , if i comment out the whole `onCreateOptionsMenu(..)`( **menu-contains a shareActionProvider** ) inside the fragment then everything works fine. P.S this problem occurs after i switch to constraintLayout..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue you're fighting ...

I recently upgraded my support library dependencies.  With support libraries `27.1.0` I was getting this exception with proven code.  I'm using `27.0.2` now.  This exception is gone.

Not tested or proven, but thought it might help.

**Edit**

I'm not sure what is wrong with `27.1.0`.  I've had to back up a minor release in the past to resolve from upgrading to the latest support libraries.  I guess nobody's perfect.  I believe `27.0.2` is the latest release prior to `27.1.0`

**Edit 2**

[Here's a link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73981395) to the issue on Googles Issue Tracker.  It's marked fixed February 28, 2018.  Should be released soon.

**Edit 3**

Confirmed fixed in `27.1.1`

Comment: thanks a lot for your response , but i want to know why should i drop to `27.0.2` or `27.0.3` is it a bug in `27.1.0` ?

Comment: It's a bug, pretty sure.

Comment: It's now fixed in `27.1.1`: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-1-1

Comment: Confirmed that the fix is in 27.1.1 ("ShareActionProvider throws ClassCastException in 27.1.0" from link Morgillo posted above)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. It is bug. SharedActionProvider throws exception in 27.1.0 
It got resolved after upgrading to 27.1.1
Hope this will help.
Have a look at this link 
[Fixed issues in 27.1.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-1-1)